# Visual C Runtime functions unresolved with `/MT`

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm converting a large Visual Studio solution from VS 2010 to VS 2017. One of the projects in the solution contains only C, no C++, and compiles with `/MT` to link statically with the multi-threaded C runtime.

Unfortunately, the C runtime functions don't seem to be getting found by the linker, even though `libcmt.lib` is in the list of libraries. The linker actually says that this lib is unused in the verbose output.

Why is the linker not finding the functions?

Output:

```
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memcpy referenced in function FsConvertAndFreeInformation
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function FsInitDebugSocket
msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcsstr referenced in function FsGetTokenInformation
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcscat_s referenced in function FsGetTokenInformation
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcsncpy_s referenced in function FsGetTokenInformation
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wcsdup referenced in function LsaApLogonUserEx2
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcscpy referenced in function SetUnicodeString
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcslen referenced in function FsDebugLog
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wcsicmp referenced in function LsaApLogonUserEx2
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strlen referenced in function AnsiToUnicode
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol free referenced in function LsaApLogonUserEx2
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mbstowcs referenced in function AnsiToUnicode
redacted.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf referenced in function _vsnwprintf_l
msvcrt.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initterm referenced in function "int __cdecl dllmain_crt_process_attach(struct HINSTANCE__ * const,void * const)" (?dllmain_crt_process_attach@@YAHQEAUHINSTANCE__@@QEAX@Z)
msvcrt.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initterm_e referenced in function "int __cdecl dllmain_crt_process_attach(struct HINSTANCE__ * const,void * const)" (?dllmain_crt_process_attach@@YAHQEAUHINSTANCE__@@QEAX@Z)
msvcrt.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
msvcrt.lib(tncleanup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_type_info_destroy_list referenced in function "void __cdecl __scrt_uninitialize_type_info(void)" (?__scrt_uninitialize_type_info@@YAXXZ)
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_dll referenced in function __scrt_dllmain_exception_filter
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl __scrt_narrow_argv_policy::configure_argv(void)" (?configure_argv@__scrt_narrow_argv_policy@@SAHXZ)
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl __scrt_narrow_environment_policy::initialize_environment(void)" (?initialize_environment@__scrt_narrow_environment_policy@@SAHXZ)
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initialize_onexit_table referenced in function __scrt_initialize_onexit_tables
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _register_onexit_function referenced in function _onexit
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _execute_onexit_table referenced in function __scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_c
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crt_atexit referenced in function _onexit
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crt_at_quick_exit referenced in function at_quick_exit
msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cexit referenced in function __scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_c
msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol terminate referenced in function __scrt_unhandled_exception_filter

Unused libraries:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\odbc32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\odbccp32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x64\libcmt.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\user32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\gdi32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\winspool.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\comdlg32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\shell32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\ole32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\oleaut32.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64\uuid.lib
```

Compiler command line options:

```
/FR"x64\ReleaseU\"
/GS
/W2
/Zc:wchar_t
/Zi
/Gm-
/Od
/Fd"x64\ReleaseU\vc141.pdb"
/Zc:inline
/fp:precise
/D "WIN32"
/D "NDEBUG"
/D "_WINDOWS"
/D "_MBCS"
/D "_USRDLL"
/D "SECURITY_WIN32"
/D "REDACTED_EXPORTS"
/D "UNICODE"
/D "_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION=1"
/D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600"
/D "_WINDLL"
/D "_UNICODE"
/errorReport:prompt
/WX
/Zc:forScope
/Gd
/MT
/FC
/Fa"x64\ReleaseU\"
/EHsc
/nologo
/Fo"x64\ReleaseU\"
/Fp"x64\ReleaseU\redacted.pch"
/diagnostics:classic
```

Linker command line options:

```
/OUT:"C:\Devel\redacted\src\x64\ReleaseU\redacted.dll"
/MANIFEST
/PDB:"C:\Devel\redacted\src\pdbmap/x64/redacted.pdb"
/DYNAMICBASE:NO
"odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "netapi32.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "Ws2_32.lib" "authz.lib" "libcmt.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"
/DEF:".\redacted.def"
/IMPLIB:"C:\Devel\redacted\src\x64\ReleaseU\redacted.lib"
/DEBUG
/DLL 
/MACHINE:X64 
/INCREMENTAL:NO 
/PGD:"C:\Devel\redacted\src\x64\ReleaseU\redacted.pgd" 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"x64\ReleaseU\redacted.dll.intermediate.manifest" 
/MAP":C:\Devel\redacted\src\pdbmap/x64/redacted.map" 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
/NOLOGO 
/VERBOSE 
/NODEFAULTLIB 
/TLBID:1
```

Comment: I just want to add that I have searched for others having similar issues here (and elsewhere) and haven't been able to find a solution yet. This project was building fine with VS 2010 and only encountered this after converting it to VS 2017.

Comment: The /NODEFAULTLIB linker option is quite dangerous.  Normally it is used to suppress an important warning, telling you that you couldn't use /MT.  All the code you link must be compiled with /MT, libraries as well.  If you ensured that was already done correctly then just remove the option.

Comment: Yeah, I know. This particular project has always used `/NODEFAULTLIB`. I think it has something to do with it being an [LSA Authentication Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/authentication-packages).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that these functions were moved in Visual C++ 2015 into `vcruntime.lib` and `libucrt.lib`.

Since this project has `/NODEFAULTLIB`, these two libs need to be added to the Additional Dependencies.